# Unwanted external RPM requirements when packaging a play 2.5 app with sbt-native-packager

Tags: java, rpm, playframework-2.5, sbt-native-packager

I have a play project which uses the sbt-native-packager to build an RPM for production distribution on centOS 7.  After updating to play 2.5 (from play 2.3), the RPM builds successfully, but has 3 dependencies that are not explicitly added to the project and not packaged with the RPM, causing the RPM installation to fail.  I have been able to verify that these packages are not necessary for the play application by installing the built RPM with `rpm -ivh [rpm package name] --nodeps` and thoroughly testing the application.  No settings have changed for the native-packager in the migration mentioned above.  I assume these are optional dependencies that are somehow being marked as required, but I can't seem to find where they are being included or how I could exclude them.  There are 3 dependencies/artifacts that I don't need that are being included shown in the RPM build output:  `Requires: osgi(com.springsource.org.joda.time) osgi(com.typesafe.sslconfig) osgi(org.slf4j.api)`

How can I find out what is causing these to be marked as required by the sbt-native-packager system?  I am fine with either including them within the RPM or, preferrably, removing them as requirements.

project plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")
```

build.sbt snippet:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8","-Xlint")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  if (sys.props("java.specification.version") != "1.8")
    sys.error("Java 8 is required for this project.")
}

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

rpmVendor := "myCompany"

packageDescription in Rpm := "app description"

packageSummary in Rpm := "summary"

rpmLicense := Some("All rights reserved.")

rpmRequirements := Seq("java-1.8.0-openjdk")
```

Log output snippet from building the RPM

```
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:12    [info] Processing files: myApp-1.1.0-1471637575326_play_2.5_experimental_3498585.noarch
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Provides: config(myApp) = 1.1.0-1471637575326_play_2.5_experimental_3498585 osgi(ch.qos.logback.classic) = 1.1.7 osgi(ch.qos.logback.core) = 1.1.7 osgi(classmate) = 1.1.0 osgi(com.avaje.ebean) = 4.2.0 osgi(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations) = 2.7.1 osgi(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core) = 2.7.1 osgi(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind) = 2.7.1 osgi(com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8) = 2.7.1 osgi(com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310) = 2.7.1 osgi(com.google.guava) = 19.0.0 osgi(com.google.inject) = 4.0.0 osgi(com.google.inject.assistedinject) = 4.0.0 osgi(com.jolbox.bonecp) = 0.8.0 osgi(com.typesafe.akka.actor) = 2.4.4 osgi(com.typesafe.akka.slf4j) = 2.4.4 osgi(com.typesafe.akka.stream) = 2.4.4 osgi(com.typesafe.config) = 1.3.0 osgi(com.typesafe.sslconfig) = 0.2.1 osgi(com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka) = 0.2.1 osgi(com.zaxxer.HikariCP) = 2.4.3 osgi(io.netty.buffer) = 4.0.36 osgi(io.netty.codec) = 4.0.36 osgi(io.netty.codec-http) = 4.0.36 osgi(io.netty.common) = 4.0.36 osgi(io.netty.handler) = 4.0.36 osgi(io.netty.transport) = 4.0.36 osgi(javassist) = 3.20.0 osgi(javax.el-api) = 3.0.0 osgi(javax.validation.api) = 1.1.0 osgi(jcl.over.slf4j) = 1.7.19 osgi(joda-time) = 2.9.2 osgi(jul.to.slf4j) = 1.7.19 osgi(net.jodah.typetools) = 0.4.4 osgi(org.apache.commons.codec) = 1.10.0 osgi(org.apache.commons.lang3) = 3.4.0 osgi(org.h2) = 1.4.191 osgi(org.hibernate.validator) = 5.2.4 osgi(org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging) = 3.2.1 osgi(org.joda.convert) = 1.8.1 osgi(org.jsr-305) = 3.0.1 osgi(org.reactivestreams.reactive-streams) = 1.0.0 osgi(org.scala-lang.modules.scala-java8-compat) = 0.7.0 osgi(org.scala-lang.modules.scala-parser-combinators) = 1.0.4 osgi(org.scala-lang.modules.scala-xml) = 1.0.1 osgi(org.scala-lang.scala-library) = 2.11.7 osgi(org.scala-lang.scala-reflect) = 2.11.7 osgi(org.yaml.snakeyaml) = 1.16.0 osgi(slf4j.api) = 1.7.21 myApp = 1.1.0-1471637575326_play_2.5_experimental_3498585
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(pre): /bin/sh
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(post): /bin/sh
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(preun): /bin/sh
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires(postun): /bin/sh
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Requires: osgi(com.springsource.org.joda.time) osgi(com.typesafe.sslconfig) osgi(org.slf4j.api)
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:21    [info] Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /mnt/bamboo_storage/bamboo_home_xml-data/build-dir/94371843/PAT-PWBP-JOB1/target/rpm/buildroot
build   19-Aug-2016 14:13:41    [info] Wrote: /mnt/bamboo_storage/bamboo_home_xml-data/build-dir/94371843/PAT-PWBP-JOB1/target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/myApp-1.1.0-1471637575326_play_2.5_experimental_3498585.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: When using a spec file, I can specify 'autoreqprov=no'. Maybe you can set this setting in your configuration files. This will tell rpmbuild not to try to automatically determine dependencies..

Comment: @ChrisMaes I was able to use the following in my build.sbt to use your suggestion.  `rpmAutoreq in Rpm := "no"`  It doesn't fix the underlying problem, but works around the RPM packaging issue until I can figure out where those dependencies are coming from.  Thanks!